# Numerology Calculator

Tags: javascript

I've built the beginnings of a numerology calculator, and would like an experienced javascript developer to review this code.

It works as expected, but I can't help but think there is a better way to write it instead of using multiple for loops.

There are a few calculations that have to be made, so I can't see any way around it. Any direction would be great.

```
function addNumbers(arr, fn) {
    var arrayTotal = [],
    singleDigits = [];

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arrayTotal.push(
            fn(arr[i])
        );   
    }

    for (value in arrayTotal) {
        for (num in arrayTotal[value]) {
            singleDigits.push(parseInt(arrayTotal[value][num]));
        }
    }

    for (i = 0, sum = 0; i < singleDigits.length; i++) {
        sum += singleDigits[i];
    }


    for (i = 0, numericValue = 0, sum = fn(sum); i < sum.length; i++) {
        numericValue += parseInt(sum[i]);
    }

    return numericValue;
}

function splitNumbers(item) {
    return item.toString().split('');
}


var value = addNumbers([13, 11, 1938], splitNumbers);
document.body.innerHTML = value;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` and `reduce` are tailor made for problems like this.

To understand the `while` loop in the final version of the code at the bottom of this post, it may help to consider a "longhand" version that does the same thing:

```
// this sets the answer we seek to the sum of all the digits
// of every number passed in via the array
finalAnswer = addDigits(combinedDigits);

// but since this sum may still be larger than a 1 digit 
// number (ie, 10 or more), we need to continue the summing
// the digits until we end up with a single digit number
while ( finalAnswer > 9 ) {
  // this converts an integer to a string
  combinedDigits = '' + finalAnswer;
  // this sums the digits again
  finalAnswer = addDigits(combinedDigits);
}
```

Here's the final, complete version, with the more compact while loop.  We are simply combining some of the steps above.

```
function addDigitsRecursively(arr) {

  var combinedDigits = arr.join(''), finalAnswer;

  while ( (finalAnswer = addDigits(combinedDigits)) > 9 )
    combinedDigits = '' + finalAnswer;

  function addDigits(str) {
    return str.split('').map(function(n) {return parseInt(n)})
                        .reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;})
  }

  return finalAnswer;
}

var value = addDigitsRecursively([13, 11, 1938]);
document.body.innerHTML = value;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the extra time to explain this to me, Jonah. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some changes I'd recommend making:

**Code correctness and readability**

- It's best to end all lines with a semi-colon. The [Google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml) agrees with me on this, as does David Herman, author of Effective JavaScript (which you should read). JavaScript actually has quite complicated auto-semicolon insertion rules, so you can get unexpected results if you lazily rely on the auto-semicolon-insertion.
- You should put some comments in. I shouldn't need to know anything about numerology to at least have a rough idea of what you're trying to accomplish with your function. Consider automating this process slightly with [JSDoc](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/).
- Some people don't like direct manipulation of `innerHTML`. You can read up on that vs other `DOM manipulation` options in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036995/is-it-wrong-to-insert-elements-using-text-and-innerhtml) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364748/change-the-options-array-of-a-select-list) SO post. It's not really important to your code here, but you should be aware of this going forward.
- You should always be using `var` to declare a variable, and you should always be declaring those variables at the top of your function since they will be `hoisted` anyway. Read more about variable hoisting in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645348/javascript-variable-hoisting-explanation).

**Efficiency**

- `map` and `reduce` are widely supported by many browers. I suspect you read some outdated information. Check out this [table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) of browser coverage of ECMAScript standards. So you should use them.

**Robustness**

- Your code is structured expecting a two-dimensional array as the shape of `arrayTotal` but this actually depends on the parameter `fn`. You should do some checking before you enter the second loop, since a user could pass in a `fn` that does not conform to this expectation (and similarly specify this expectation or requirement in your comments as to what the function does and what its parameters hsould be). This is a general comment and not specific to JavaScript though this particular problem is fairly specific to loosely typed languages like JavaScript.

Comment: *"David Herman, the original creator of JavaScript"* - It wasn't Brendan Eich?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer ugh you are right. Just corrected the post. I often confuse those 2 names, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based off of Jonah's. This removes the re-stringification which reduces the code size by instead overwriting the previous result with the new result, and using that as the input. It splits the number, adds the components, then sets the input to the output and repeats.

The `+b` operator is shorthand for converting a string into an int.

---

```
function addDigits(inputArray) {
  str = inputArray.join('')
  while ((str = str.split('').reduce((a, b) => +a + +b)+'') > 9);
  return +str
}

console.log(addDigits([13, 11, 1938]))
>>> 9
```

It could be simplified further, but is getting into incomprehensible-ness territory:

```
function addDigits(c) {
    while ((c = (c + '').split('').reduce((a, b) => (+a || 0) + (+b || 0))) > 9);
    return c
}
```

If `.split('')` is not allowed, then...

```
function addDigits(c) {
    c = c.join('')
    while ((c = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(Math.log10(c)))
                .keys())
            .map(p => Math.floor(c % Math.pow(10, p + 1) / Math.pow(10, p)))
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b)) > 9);
    return c
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just thought I'd post this. After reading up on `map()` and `reduce()`, I've realised they are only supported by IE9+. Taking some inspiration from Jonah's post, I've managed to slim down the code using two for loops. See below.

```
function mapForEach(arr) {
    var combinedNumbers = arr.join(''),
        totalValue = 0,
        finalValue = 0; 

    for (i = 0; i < combinedNumbers.length; i++) {
        totalValue += parseInt(combinedNumbers[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0, totalValue += ''; i < totalValue.length; i++) {
        finalValue += parseInt(totalValue[i]);
    }

    return finalValue;
}

var myArray = [13, 11, 1938],
    value = mapForEach(myArray);

document.body.innerHTML = value;
```

Comment: jaybee, there are polyfills for both map and reduce if you need full IE support.  Check the MDN docs for those functions, they will include the polyfills, which you can just copy and paste into your code.  Then you can use map and reduce without fear of breaking older browsers.  I recommend this approach, since the methods are so useful and so much more readable than loops.  FYI: I was not the one who downvoted this post.